# Using datamash in Bash script on txt file without columns

Tags: bash

I have a .txt file which has 5 values.
They are printed under each other like this:

505899

504536

503248

503826

504728

Now I want to use datamash to get the average and the standard deviation. I tried this:

```
    datamash mean 1 sstdev 1 < myfile.txt
```

But it says:

```
    datamash: invalid numeric value in line 1 field 1: '505899 '
```

My .txt doesn't have columns. Does datamash need one?
If it  does need a column, how can I add one in Bash?
And can I place the results in a new file like this:

```
    datamash mean 1 sstdev 1 < myfile.txt >results.txt
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check your file for trailing whitespaces or special characters, it looks like datamash receives an extra character after the digits. You can use `cat -A file` (display `\n` as `$` and other special characters as their [caret notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation)) or `xxd file` (show hex codes of the characters)

Comment: Thanks, I had one whitespace after the data, now it works